# How do I document that a function allows an arbitrary amount of arguments in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I have a few functions that accept an arbitrary amount of arguments. I've checked out the [JSDoc @Param](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagParam) wiki but it doesn't mention the issue. How would you, for instance, document a function like `console.log`?

Comment: I actually found the right way to do it, look at my answer with links.

Comment: I agree this question is a duplicate.